# Collectd: Execute external script after threshold is being reached

Tags: monitoring, collectd

I am using collectd for collecting system information. I would like to add threshold detection and do the following action if a threshold is being reached:

1. Send e-mail
2. Run an external script

I would like to combine the two action into one script and in the script both action will be executed. I am looking at the example in collectd but I failed finding relevant information.

Thanks in advance